# Bash command using variables

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, sh

I want to batch covert files in a directory with a program.
I want news files to keep old names, apart from the new extension.
To illustrate, a single conversion would go like this:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" world_borders.json world_borders.shp
```

(meaning, `program options out-file in-file`)

Now, I want to do this with all .shp files in a directory, to get .json files.
How do I create a bash script like this?

I already did

```
for file in *.shp ; 
do ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" "${file}" "${file}".json; 
done
```

But it didnt work. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parameter expansion to remove the extension from a file name:

```
#! /bin/bash
dir=$1
for file in "$dir"/*.shp ; do
    ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON "${file%.shp}".json "$file"
done
```

Save to `ogr.sh`, make executable, call with

```
ogr.sh /path/to/dir
```

Comment: I added a comment of what I did and it didnt work.
Would you care to comment on that?

Comment: @toninoj: In your first example, it's `output input`. In your update, it's `input output`.

Comment: @toninoj  Also, what you did is not what choroba suggested.

Comment: I see that my solution is wrong, as @choroba suggested.
But his example also returns error.
`
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `/*.shp' with the following drivers.`

Comment: And when I changed to `output input` as it should be (in my update), I got the error multiplied for every shp file  want to convert.

Comment: @toninoj: It seems you didn't provide the `dir` argument.

Comment: Im saving the script in the same directory, so I presumed it would presume it.

Comment: @toninoj: You have to add code to do that. You can check the source - there's nothing special about $1 being empty. Or, just run it in the correct dir with `ogr.sh .`.

Comment: This may have been an issue of ogr2ogr & shx files being present. I believe your example will work.